# quoteExactInputSingle is returning error

Tags: solidity, uniswap, solidity-0.8.x, uniswapv3

I'm working on solidity code that uses pancakeswapV3 `quoter` contract to call `quoteExactInputSingle`. Here is the code snippet

```
function AnalyseTnx(address tokenPath0,address tokenPath1,uint256 amtIn)external returns (uint256)
    {
        IQuoter quoter;
        quoter=IQuoter(0xB048Bbc1Ee6b733FFfCFb9e9CeF7375518e25997);       
        return quoter.quoteExactInputSingle(tokenPath0, tokenPath1, 100, amtIn, 0);
     }
```

the arguments i passed are

```
tokenPath0=0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955
tokenPath1=0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56
amtIn=100000000000000000000000
```

but when i test using hardhat it results

```
 Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-UNPREDICTABLE_GAS_LIMIT ] (reason="Transaction reverted without a reason string"
```

i double checked that the pool for the pair is exist with 500 fee. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have misplaced arguments. Fourth argument is fee and it is uint24, you pass amtIn there which is bigger

[image]